# Delete Particular Number from Call Log Programatically in Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, calllog

I want to delete a particular number from the call log. The number is like this - "*#6666#*".

I am doing this:

```
String queryString = "NUMBER=" + number;

    try {
        context.getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                queryString, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The main problem occurs when I use *# before and after and gives a Runtime exception. Without that everything works fine.

Can anyone give me a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have following permission in manifast.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
```

for Deleting Call logs for particular number try this:

```
public void DeleteCallLogByNumber(String strNumber ) {   
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " = ? ", strNumber , "");
    int idOfRowToDelete= cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls._ID));
    getContentResolver().delete(Uri.withAppendedPath(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(idOfRowToDelete)), "", null);
    }  
}
```

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal : I think the OP has already mentioned in his question about his error/problem.

Comment: please complete your code like **strNumber** and  **idOfRowToDelete**.